# Vaadin 23 add favicon to non-PWA application

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I removed @PWA annotation from my Application. Now I need to add a favicon. I know how to add favicon to the PWA Vaadin application, but how to do the same for non-PWA application? Where it should be placed and how to configure it?

Comment: Check out https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/loading-resources#resource-cheat-sheet

Comment: I tried to place it under /src/main/webapp/favicon.icon - it doesn't work

Comment: Also, I have META-INF/resources folder. Maybe it should be placed somewhere there?

Comment: Works now, thanks! In additional to what suggested above, I added ignore rule to my Spring security and added exclusion to my Maven resource filtering. Thanks for the help!